# How to use a SACSegmentation after a Voxel Filter in PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I want to use a SACsegmentation after a Voxel filter, but the output of the filter is a `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` while the `seg.setInputCloud` method of the algorithm requires a `pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr`.
I found in other topic that the following line could be used `pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(*cloud_filtered, *filt_cloudPtr);` to make the conversion, but it is not working.

Here is the function I am trying to implement:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 process_cloud(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2* cloud = new pcl::PCLPointCloud2;
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr cloudPtr(cloud);
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud_filtered;

  pcl_conversions::toPCL(*input, *cloud);

  pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
  sor.setInputCloud (cloudPtr);
  sor.setLeafSize (0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
  sor.filter (cloud_filtered);

  pcl::PCLPointCloud2ConstPtr filt_cloudPtr(new pcl::PCLPointCloud2);

  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(*cloud_filtered, *filt_cloudPtr);

  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
  // Create the segmentation object
  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> seg;
  // Optional
  seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
  // Mandatory
  seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);

  seg.setInputCloud (filt_cloudPtr);
  seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `pcl::PCLPointCloud2`, why don't you use `pcl::PointXYZRGB`.

```
void cloudReceive(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& inputMsg){
  pcl::fromROSMsg(*inputMsg, *tempCloud);

  pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZRGB> vg;
  vg.setInputCloud(tempCloud);
  vg.setLeafSize(vgleaf, vgleaf, vgleaf);
  vg.filter(*tempCloud);


  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices);
  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients(new pcl::ModelCoefficients);

  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZRGB> seg;
  seg.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);
  seg.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
  seg.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  seg.setMaxIterations(maxIter);
  seg.setDistanceThreshold(disThres);

  seg.setInputCloud(tempCloud);
  seg.segment(*inliers, *coefficients);

  if(inliers->indices.size() == 0){
    std::cout << "no planar found" << std::endl;
  }

  pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ei;
  ei.setInputCloud(input);
  ei.setIndices(inliers);
  ei.setNegative(false);
  ei.filter(*BackCloud);
  ei.setNegative(true);
  ei.filter(*tempCloud);


  pcl::toROSMsg(*tempCloud, outputMsg);
  pclpub.publish(outputMsg);
  tempCloud->clear();
}
```

Comment: Hello there @Kevin I Apriandy. thanks for your answer. I had the same problem and by reading your answer and other online resources, I found that `SACSegmentation` has not been implemented to be used with `pcl::PCLPointCloud2`. so we need to use it with another type as you have mentioned in your answer. because I am not very experienced in cpp and PCL, I want to know whether I have understood the problem correctly or not.